# Get current user in invitation_instruction mailer

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise-invitable

I am using devise_invitable gem for sending invitation. In my mail content I have the following:
“Name Here” has invited you to join .....
Where "Name Here" is the current user who has invited to join....
I am not getting the current_user in invitation_instruction mailer.
How can I get the current_user in users/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb?
Had also used @resource.invited_by but still not able to get anything.

Comment: Can some one please give any solution.

Comment: if you found your solution please post it..i need it too..

Comment: In the controller I used @ sender = current_user and then used @ sender in my mailer

Comment: oh ya did the same...thanks